# VLC can't open stream on Google Compute Instance

Tags: azure, google-compute-engine

I have a weird situation and I hope someone will be able to assist.
I'm using VLC (latest version) to open (pull) RTSP stream on Microsoft Azure (Windows 2012 R2). **The stream works great**.

When I'm using a Google compute instance with the same OS (Windows 2012 R2)and the same VLC player (same version) **the stream doesn't open and I'm getting 0 video blocks**.
Trying to open the same stream on Google Compute Instance with Windows 2008 R2 causes VLC to crash.

When I'm trying to open the same stream on various private machines (not on the cloud) the streams opens well.

I have no idea what could be the problem.
If I'm trying to isolate the problem I think the problem relates to Google Cloud network...but I might be wrong here...

Do you have any suggestion how to overcome this issue?

thanks,
R.

Comment: I tried VLC latest version to open RTSP streams on both GCE VMs with Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 2012 R2 and worked with no problem. I used the following test streams:   http://www.wowza.com/html/mobile.html

Comment: do you have problem with specific RTSP stream? if so send me the link and I can test it.

Comment: rtsp://80.178.207.104:554?tcp

Answer (score 1):

I created two GCE VMs with Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 2012 R2 as operating system. All on default settings. Installed latest version of VLC player (v2.2.0) and test with RTSP streams from this link: wowza.com/html/mobile.html

Worked perfectly.

You may check your Windows firewall or network firewall, if you've changed it from the default settings.

Comment: checked the firewall - it's well configured.